# Saving records recursively with Mongoid, Ancestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have a model `Line Items` embedded in `Line` model. In Line create view, I have provided ability to define multiple nested levels of line items.

Here is a random snap of `param[:line]`:

```
=> {"title"=>"Hello", "type"=>"World", "line_items"=>{"1"=>{"name"=>"A", 
    "position"=>"1", "children"=>{"1"=>{"name"=>"A1", "position"=>"1", 
    "children"=>{"1"=>{"name"=> "A11", "position"=>"1"}, "2"=>{"name"=>"A12",
    "position"=>"2"}}}, "2"=>{"name"=>"A2", "position"=>"2"}}}, "3"=>
    {"name"=>"B", "position"=>"3"}}}
```

In Line#create, I have:

```
def create
  @line = Line.new(params[:line])

  if @line.save
    save_lines(params[:line][:line_items])
    flash[:success] = "Line was successfully created."
    redirect_to line_path 
  else
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
```

In Line#save_lines, I have:

```
# Save children up to fairly infinite nested levels.. as much as it takes!
def save_lines(parent)
  unless parent.blank?
    parent.each do |i, values|
      new_root = @line.line_items.create(values)
      unless new_root[:children].blank?
        new_root[:children].each do |child|
          save_lines(new_root.children.create(child))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

LineItem Model looks like:

```
class LineItem
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Ancestry
  has_ancestry

  # Fields
  field :name,        type: String,
  field :type,        type: String
  field :position,    type: Integer
  field :parent_id,   type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId

  attr_accessible :name, :type, :url, :position, :parent_id

  # Associations
  embedded_in :line, :inverse_of => :line_items
end
```

in Line model, i have:

```
# Associations
embeds_many :line_items, cascade_callbacks: true
```

Which work as expected. But, is there a better way to save the line_items recursively with Ancestry?

Comment: I solved this a few days ago. Had a very similar need to recursively create objects. But do you also need the inner objects to be associated(has_many) with the outer objects? In my case, they were needed to be.

Comment: No the inner objects have no association. Actually i normalized its association to form a flat document (table).

Comment: Check out the Mongoid docs on recursive embedding: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html

You should not need to use Ancestry for this at all.

And here is the docs for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/nested_attributes.html

This enables your params hash for your Line model to include your embedded line items and it creates the objects automagically. (Also available in ActiveRecord, FYI)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code looks fine. I just refactored it.
How about:

```
def save_lines(parent)
  parent.each do |i, values|
    #get children hash if any
    children = values.delete("children")
    # create the object with whatever remain in values hash
    @line.line_items.create(values)
    # recurse if children isn't empty
    save_lines(children) if children
  end
end
```